# Is there a tool I can use to find albums related to a set of albums?

Tags: similar-artists

Good morning everybody!

I'm thinking about the possibility of listening to new music that is ***related to a set of albums***, similar to what Spotify suggests related to specific albums you hear a lot or started listening recently (I don't really know the criteria). Notice that I'm not "asking" Spotify to do this per se, but it does it automatically when I open the home screen, I have to find the suggestions area and get artists related to those albums.

For example: I really like the albums "Ten" (pearl jam) and "One hot minute" (RHCP), I guess the way the app suggests "new" music to you is by using the tags of the songs/album, so it would be perfectly reasonable to do it with a set of albums let's say I could add "¿Dónde jugarán las niñas?" (Molotov) to the mix, and find related albums to those three as well.

Is there a tool I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about finding music based on *albums* but you can find music based on the similarity of bands by using [Music Map](https://www.music-map.com/pearl+jam)

I've personally discovered some great bands this way